# Ionic/Angular Issue Cannot find module './fs'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I have installed node v10 and trying to install Ionic in my mac.

When I run `sudo npm install -g ionic`, it shows ionic 4 installed successfully.

But when  run `ionic -v` or `ionic serve`, it shows the following error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:6:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

I have searched for the solution but I could not find any working solution for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: P.S. It is strongly advised to **not** run `npm install -g` with `sudo`. See https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally if you're having trouble globally installing packages without `sudo`.

Comment: @Edric You are right. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Edric Comment helped me out.

`It is strongly advised to not run npm install -g with sudo.`

I uninstalled the ionic and reinstalled without sudo and now it is working just great.

Thank you @Edric.

Comment: All Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are facing this issues is because you have installed Ionic with root permission. So `ionic -v` is not able to access installed files.

Try with `sudo` i.e. `sudo ionic -v`